# textview.settext in Fragment Doesn't Work After First Call

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to update a textview in my fragment based on what a user clicks. When I first load the activity it sets the textview. But later, even though the textview.settext does get called, nothing seems to change.

In my activity I send the new  variable like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.pager1, SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 2", nonStaticRandomInfoSt), "tag").commit();
```

My Fragment:

```
 public static SecondFragment newInstance(int page, String title, String randomInfo) {
    SecondFragment fragmentSecond = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    args.putString("randomInfo", randomInfo);
    fragmentSecond.setArguments(args);


    return fragmentSecond;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    randomInfo = this.getArguments().getString("randomInfo");




}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);


    TextView randomInfoTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.randomInfo);

    randomInfoTV.setText(randomInfo); //this is getting called, but it's not changing the textview
    randomInfoTV.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


    return view;
}
```

Edit:

I have a fragment in a viewpager. When the activity is first entered, a default value is set to the textview in the fragment. From a listview in my activity layout, the user can make a selection. When an item is selected, I call the fragment manager and pass the new randomInfo variable. I want to update the textview in the fragment. I know the correct value is being passed by debugging, and I know that the textview.settext is being called as well. But for some reason, the textview remains unchanged. Do you have any suggestions as to why this is happening? I don't even know where to start in fixing it.

How I create the fragments:

```
    public static class MyPagerAdapter1 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

    public MyPagerAdapter1(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1", imageURL);

            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 2", randomInfoSt);


            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Click event code;

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (!fromservice) {
                Log.i(TAG, "about to start service");

             //starting service code...


                initFragmentVars(position); //this runs the fragmentmanager transaction

            }
```

Comment: where else do you do settext ? i only see one

Comment: what is `nonStaticRandomInfoSt `, maybe it was never changed?

Comment: Please explain how the user interacts with your app and what happens. Then explain what you **want** to happen.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Have you looked at my edit? What other information can I provide?

Comment: @MJDude Thank you for the edit, however you still have not answer **where else** do you set the text and **when** are you expecting it to change?

Comment: @cricket_007 The text is set when the fragment is first created, and I expect it to change when an item in a listview is clicked.

Comment: Okay, where is your click event code, then?

Comment: I added it. But I don't think the problem is there. I think I'm somehow the fact that I'm using a viewpager is messing stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text in `public void onViewCreated(final View view, final Bundle savedInstanceState);` instead of `onCreateView()`.

The later is ok for what you're doing (findViewById()) but the binding of the data + the view, should be done after the views have been created, especially inside a Fragment.

<sub>*I know this is confusing, but Android Lifecycle is a mess created by dozens of different software engineers and here we are…*</sub>

Comment: This does not make a significant difference.

Comment: It does if you're using fragments. There's a reason for the callback to exist.

Comment: No it doesn't.  The way the op is doing it is perfectly fine

Comment: I'm not going to argue with someone who has a different opinion. I consider using that callback to bind the data a *bad practice*, which makes it even harder to unit test. The creation of the view is a chore on the Android side. The binding of the data should not be tied to it. The OP has not shown enough code to explain what his real problem is, yet I would still ask him to move the binding code to onViewCreated.

Comment: Ok. So you are actual suggesting an improvement to the design, not how to fix the problem. That is reasonable as long as you do not pass of your suggestion as a fix.

Comment: You don't seem to grasp the concept of separating the initialization logic from the view hierarchy inflation/creation logic. On the other hand there is no "fix to the problem" because the OP didn't provide enough information yet (or ever). onCreateView is a rough equivalent of onCreate() @ Activity Level, despite the Fragment's own onCreate() method. FragmentManager guarantees certain things in onViewCreated and one should benefit from those. Source: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/3f453164ec884d26a556477027b430cb22a9b7e3/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L2047

Comment: of course I understand separation of concerns. My original comment still stands. By "no significant difference" I mean that your suggestion will not produce any change in behavior and therefore does not actually answer the question. As you say, the OP does not provide enough information to diagnose the problem.